# trying to get a speed variable, TypeError: an integer is required

Tags: python, variables, serial-port, typeerror

so im programming a robot using a raspberry pi using input commands from a xbox controller from a laptop. programming using python 2.7

im getting an error when trying to use the magnitude from the axis of the controller get speed control on the motors.

but if i declare a definite number for the speed it works.
but if i use the magnitude it gives an error, even tho if i print the variable is shows up just fine.

This is the error i get

```
executing forward...
max speed is
23
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "driverMain.py", line 103, in <module>
main()
File "driverMain.py", line 69, in main
frontCon.allForward(maxSpeed)
File "/home/pi/xbox/sabretooth.py", line 11, in allForward
self.leftMotor.drive('forward', speed)
File "/home/pi/xbox/sabretooth.py", line 32, in drive
self.port.write(chr(speed))
TypeError: an integer is required
```

*part of code on pc

```
def joyStickMovement(magnitude, command, joyStickNum):
host = '192.168.1.112'
port = 12345
sock = socket.socket()
sock.connect((host,port))

prefix = ""
if joyStickNum == 1:
    prefix = "bucket"

sock.send(str(prefix + command) + '|' + str(magnitude))
```

*part of code on raspberry

```
frontCon = controller(serialPort, baudRate, 130)
rearCon = controller(serialPort, baudRate, 129)


#set up socket
host = ''
port = 12345
sock = socket.socket()
sock.bind((host,port))

sock.listen(5)
while True:
    c, addr = sock.accept()
    command,maxSpeed = c.recv(1024).split('|')

    print(command)
    print(maxSpeed)
#### this print shows the speed value correctly
#### if i insert this maxspeed code  
##   maxSpeed = 120    
## here for example, the program works correctly, otherwise i get an error
## even tho without it, the print work fine

#### later in the code 
    elif command == 'forward':
        print('executing forward...')
        print('max speed is')
        print(maxSpeed)
        frontCon.allBack(maxSpeed)
        rearCon.allBack(maxSpeed)
```

*the sabertooth

```
import serial

class controller(object):
   def __init__(self, port, baudRate, address):
        self.port = serial.Serial(port, baudRate, timeout=1)
        self.address = address
        self.leftMotor = motor(self.port, address, 1)
        self.rightMotor = motor(self.port, address, 2)

    def allForward(self, speed):
        self.leftMotor.drive('forward', speed)
        self.rightMotor.drive('forward', speed)

    def allBack(self, speed):
        self.leftMotor.drive('back', speed)
        self.rightMotor.drive('back', speed)

class motor(object):
    #motorNum is 1 or 2, depending on which motor you wish to control
    def __init__(self, serial, controllerAddress, motorNum):
        self.port = serial
        self.address = controllerAddress
        self.motorNum = motorNum
        if motorNum == 1:
            self.commands = {'forward': 0, 'back': 1}
        elif motorNum == 2:
            self.commands = {'forward': 4, 'back': 5}

    def drive(self, direction, speed):
        self.port.write(chr(self.address))
        self.port.write(chr(self.commands[direction]))
        self.port.write(chr(speed))
        self.port.write(chr(int(bin((self.address + self.commands[direction] + speed) & 0b01111111), 2)))
```

i tried also adding a maxSpeed = 50 at the beginning of the script hoping maybe it would see the variable and change it to whatever it receive and send it to the motor but it still gives the same error.  i really have no clue what else to do and would appreciate any help

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After receiving and splitting based on `|`, `maxSpeed` will be a string, you need to convert that to `int` when passing to `allForward` and `allBack` like this

```
    frontCon.allBack(int(maxSpeed))
    rearCon.allBack(int(maxSpeed))
```